# using local notification data coming from web service

Tags: ios, ipad

I am new to IOS and wants to used Local Notification feature of iOS. 
my problem is i do not know if i can go with local notification. in my case data will come from web service... it is like..no specific date. default time interval is 60 Sec. after 60 sec app has to call webservice which will return notification data..and after some validation i need to push to user.
and if user click on view details it will launch appand get data via webservice.

Is using localnotification will serve my purpose? or i have to go with other approach?

Please help.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: no.you couldnt done any notification from the web via. local notification. just go through push notification  http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

Comment: but webservice is my only web service...which will only give me data..liek notification validation data and message to be push...i can not call webservice after say 60 sec. of interval and if at all data is there show notification...

Answer (score 0):

I think this 60 second thing is you polling the server every 60 seconds to fetch new data, then if there is new data post a local notification?

This is kinda possible with iOS7 but not exactly every 60 seconds, sometimes not at all, But in general it is strongly frowned upon. Instead the webserver should send push notifications when new data is available, It saves the user battery life.

On iOS7 there are silent push notifications (just don't include the alert) that can ask the client to do the validation you mentioned, and If the user needs a notification you can create a Local Notification to alert the user in a change

You should give this documentation a long look, it isn't trivial work for a new iOS programmer:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html

And here is a relevant Apple documentation quote "Local and push notifications serve different design needs. A local notification is local to an application on an iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch. Push notifications—also known as remote notifications—arrive from outside a device. They originate on a remote server—the application’s provider—and are pushed to applications on devices (via the Apple Push Notification service) when there are messages to see or data to download."

Comment: no we can not get any alert from server as such... requirement i have been told is...from app itself there will be on/off for notification to show..and if ON after every say 60Sec webservice will be called which will get data from notification table....data will be diferent column which will tell me if i have to show notification (like i will validate). if i can show that particular notification just push....

Comment: Well in that case the design patterns of iOS prevent that implementation of the feature you want. You cannot poll a server in the background on iOS. You can however program a server that sends push notifications every 60 seconds which is what Apple wants developers to do. Most Apps don't have a 60 second requirement but send push notifications when new data like a message arrives.

Comment: You can however do this to a foregrounded application no problem. But from what I've heard you need a push server

Comment: so basically in general way if my app is background i will not be able to call web service..... it is not allowed.....

Comment: As the iOS app polling it alone, its not allowed; the server pushing to the app, it is allowed. Weird I know but iOS doesn't support polling, instead it uses a very real push service. Think about it like this. You as an app can't poll your webserver, but the OS is polling the push notification server in a power efficient way. So use that method

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to achieve this functionality to happen automatically/polling (i.e without user interaction like, clicking on the view details button)- the answer is a big **NO** at least not till iOS6.x

Your application cannot run for infinite length in background at-not till ios6.x. You may have to consider using APNS service to achieve this.

Otherwise, your approach on scheduling a local notification for ever 60 sec - The user clicks in the view option - the application comes up - You make a web-service call - Get the data - Validate the received data - Uploading to the server, looks fine to happen.

Will it not be annoying to the user getting notification for ever 60 sec & operating on the app to do whatever you intended to do? - Just curious.

Comment: 60 sec may be just to get latest details..its business app..but 60 will get details ..from code i have to decided depending on data comming from DB if to push notification or not....so it is not like every 60 sec user will be get notification...but webservice need to be called ...if at all to check latest data for notification table... after getting data if it pass all validation ..the i will show notification and if user click on view detail it will launch an app and got to get perticualr data....offcourse this need user interaction...

Comment: So you are looking at polling a server from your application, this is not possible as you application cannot run for infinite time in background. Atleast not till iOS6.x